# Windows 10 randomly restarting

Tags: windows-10, reboot

My PC has started randomly restarting, usually while I'm playing a game. The screen goes black and I hear static in my headphones, then the computer reboots. It has only been happening with Windows 10, although this may be a coincidence. There is no blue screen of death. I have checked for overheating and my GPU never gets above 60 degrees. How can I fix this?

Update: Removing my GPU overclock has not fixed the issue. It just happened again while playing Dawn of War II

Specs:

AMD FX-6300 hex core processor
Radeon R7 200 series graphics with 1GB VRAM
8GB DDR3 RAM

Comment: Check the event logs for errors [What information appears in event logs? (Event Viewer)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-information-event-logs-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: @DavidPostill Under the "Critical" tab there are 6 critical errors in the last 7 days, which sounds about right. It says "kernel-power" as the source with event ID 41 and task category (63). Does this mean anything?

Comment: [Windows Kernel event ID 41 error "The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2028504)

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for the link. BugCheckCode and PowerButtonTimestamp are both zero. My GPU was overclocked so I've stopped the overclocking to see if it helps, although I have had it overclocked for at least 4-6 months so I don't know whether that was the cause.

Comment: I had a similar problem not to long ago. Turned out to be the power supply. It eventually gave out after several months of oddities.

Comment: @daBoss I agree on that one. I answered a question not too long ago that was having random reboots, especially when gaming. After eliminating a overheating CPU, the problem turned out to be a faulty PSU.